# Using httpBasic with AuthenticationEntryPoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I am following [this tutorial](https://grokonez.com/spring-framework/spring-boot/angular-spring-boot-jwt-authentication-example-angular-6-spring-security-mysql-full-stack-part-2-build-backend) on using JWT authentication with spring boot. I can login and access the api from postman as shown in the tutorial. However, when I try to do the same from the browser at localhost:8080, I get a 401 Unauthorized error.

The configure method used in the tutorial is

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
      .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll().anyRequest()
      .authenticated().and().exceptionHandling()
      .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
      .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

When I remove the authenticationEntryPoint and add httpbasic, the login dialog is displayed in the browser when accessing localhost:8080.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
      .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll().anyRequest()
      .authenticated().and().exceptionHandling()
      .and().httpBasic().and().sessionManagement()
      .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
```

But when I try to add httpBasic with authenticationEntryPoint, no login dialog is shown.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll().anyRequest()
        .authenticated().and().exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
        .and().httpBasic().and().sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

  http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

**Updated**

The `unauthorizedHandler` is an implementation of AuthenticationEntryPoint.

```
@Component
public class UnauthorizedHandler implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UnauthorizedHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,
                     HttpServletResponse response,
                     AuthenticationException e) 
                             throws IOException, ServletException {

        logger.error("Unauthorized error. Message - {}", e.getMessage());
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Error -> Unauthorized");
}
```

}

How can I display the login dialog while using AuthenticationEntryPoint?

Comment: Why do you need an custom authentication entry point? What is `unauthorizedHandler`? Show your code. `httpBasic` already adds an authentication entry point, which should be enough.

Comment: I'm following [this tutorial](https://grokonez.com/spring-framework/spring-boot/angular-spring-boot-jwt-authentication-example-angular-6-spring-security-mysql-full-stack-part-2-build-backend) to implement spring security with jwt. I have updated the code in the original question to include the `unauthorizedHandler`.

Comment: Your authentication point doesn't make anything (just logging). Remove it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little old, but I hope my answer helps someone anyway.

I was having exactly the same issue because I was trying to get the auth dialog for swagger but I wanted to handle unauthorized requests without displaying the dialog, so what I did is this:

```java
@Component
public class AuthEntryPointJwt implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthEntryPointJwt.class);

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        // Requested URL contains "swagger" since it is the only page where I wanted to display login dialog when set header to display dialog and send back the response
        if (request.getRequestURL().toString().contains("swagger")) {
            response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "BASIC");
            response.sendError(response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        } else {
            // if not, just send unauthorized error
            logger.error("Unauthorized error: {}", authException.getMessage());
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Error: Unauthorized");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default `exceptionHandling` is enabled and it uses default entry point which is  `Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint` when you set up `httpBasic()` it's setting new default entry point in `exceptionHandling` which is `BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint` - it's all about default, when non explicitly entry point is defined.

When you explicitly define new entry point `.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(some entry point)` all default configuration is not used anymore and will be used `some entry point` instead.

Note that `httpBasic` is still working, but it should tell somehow to your browser that authentification failed and tell  to the browser to ask user for credentials for http basic and it's what `BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint` is doing, by setting [appropriate header `WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="User Visible Realm"`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Server_side).

In your `UnauthorizedHandler` in `commence` add lines `String realmName = "some text";` and`response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"" + realmName + "\"");`

PS. I haven't analized your case, just told what is wrong (why not working as expected) and how to make it works - so this solution maybe not good from security perspective.